# Optimize table on huge mysql tables without partition

Tags: mysql

We have a very huge Mysql table which is MyISAM. Whenever we run optimize table command, the table is locked and performance is getting impacted. The table is not read only and hence creating temporary tables and swapping them may not work out. We are not able to partition the table also.

Is there any other way/tool to achieve optimize table functionality without degrading the performance. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `MyISAM`?

Comment: Just to have better speed in SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html

> For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which
>   rebuilds the table (...)

Therefore, I would not expect any improvement in switching to InnoDB, as Quassnoi probably suggests.

By definition, OPTIMIZE TABLE needs some exclusive access to the table, hence the degraded performances during OPTIMIZE'ation

Nevertheless, there could be some steps to take to reduce the time taken by OPTIMIZE, depending on how your table is "huge" :

- if your table has many fields, your table might need to be normalized. Conversely, you might want to de-normalize your table by spreading your columns into several "narrower" tables, and establish one-to-one relations.
- if your table has many records, implement a "manual" partitionning in your application code. A simple step would be to create an "archive" table that holds rarely updated records. This way you only need to optimize a smaller set of records (the non-archive table).

Comment: Improvement would be that you wouldn't need to `OPTIMIZE` the table.

Comment: If you keep your "active data set" (i.e. the "non-archived" table in my above post) small enough, it could very well be that you do not need to OPTIMIZE it at all, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

optimize table command lock the table,it decrease the performance.

you download percona tool kit command to optimize table.

this command not lock the table during optimize table.

use below link :

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html